# How to delete multiple checkbox in Excel by VBA?

Tags: vba

I am trying to delete multiple checkoxes using VBA.

The code i have so far is as as follows:

```
Sub DeleteCheckbox()
    Dim cb As CheckBox

    For Each cb In Sheets("Job_Card_Update").CheckBoxes
        If cb.TopLeftCell.Address = Sheets("Job_Card_Update").Range("M13:M20").Address Then cb.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Application.Intersect Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-intersect-method-excel) to tests if multiple ranges intersect, share cells with, each other.

```
Dim cb As CheckBox
With Sheets("Job_Card_Update")
    For Each cb In .CheckBoxes
        If Not Intersect(cb.TopLeftCell, .Range("M13:M20")) Is Nothing Then cb.Delete
    Next
End With
```